# Problema com header no php

Tags: php

Tenho esses mesmos arquivos em outro servidor e não dão problema, mas no servidor atual está dando. Eu só copiei os arquivos e mudei a conexao.php para o bd atual.

**apagar.php**

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/servertv/public_html/sexoebemestar/topicos/apagar.php:1) in /home/servertv/public_html/sexoebemestar/topicos/valida_sessao.php on line 1
```

**valida_sessao.php**

```
ob_start();
session_start();
if((isset ($_SESSION['usuario']) == true) and (isset ($_SESSION['senha']) == true)) 
{
    $usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];
    $senha = $_SESSION['senha'];
    $consulta = mysql_query("select * from usuarios where usuario =     '$usuario' and senha = '$senha'");
    $membro="sim";
    $dado = mysql_fetch_object($consulta);
}
    else{
        $membro = 'nao';
}
```

Comment: Como é novo na comunidade, recomendo que faça o [tour] para aprender como funciona o site e leia o guia de [ask]. Sua pergunta já foi respondida nesta outra, mas se ainda restar alguma dúvida, sinta-se a vontade para [edit] e descrever qual foi a dificuldade.

Comment: Em resumo, esse erro em si não é o problema. O problema está no seu código, provavelmente a conexão ao bd está falhando.

Comment: Não é banco de dados, há dois programas enviando o cabeçalho do HTML, no outro servidor as mensagens de debug devem estar desligadas e por esta razão não aparecem.